# Remainder of multivariate division of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, sagemath, groebner-basis, multivariate-polynomial

Consider a homogeneous polynomial of several variables $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ with the leading term (with respect to lex ordering) having the maximum degree of any $x_i$s to be $k$. Take the ideal I generated by the polynomials $\langle x_1^{k+1}-1, x_2^{k+1}-1,\ldots, x_n^{k+1}-1\rangle$. It can be seen that the polynomials that generate the ideal are a Groebner basis for the ideal.

Now, if we reduce $f$ modulo $I$. what is the remainder we could expect? From the division algorithm for the multivariate case, it is clear that the maximum degree of leading term in the remainder for each $x_i$s would be at most $k$. But, since $x_i^{k+1}$ cannot be converted to $x_i^k$ by any polynomial multiplication, I expect that the remainder must be $f$. But, when I ran an implementation on Sage, I got the remainder not equal to $f$ for the specific case $k=3$. The same process when I applied to reduce the polynomial with respect to the basis $\langle x_1^{k+2}-1,x_2^{k+2}-1,\ldots,x_n^{k+2}-1\rangle$, I got the remainder as $f$.

For example, take the polynomial 
$$f=(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)(x_1-x_6)(x_2-x_3)(x_2-x_7)(x_3-x_5)(x_3-x_9)(x_5-x_8)(x_5-x_{10})(x_8-x_4)$$
 where $x_3,x_4,x_5,x_1,x_2, x_6, x_7,x_8, x_9, x_{10}$ are variables, which is homegeneous. Now, reduction of this modulo the ideal $\langle x_1^4-1, x_2^4-1, x_3^4-1, x_4^4-1,x_5^4-1,x_6^4-1, x_7^4-1, x_8^4-1,x_9^4-1,x_{10}^4-1\rangle$ yields a non-zero remainder not equal to $f$.
The sagecode used is:

`sagemath: R.<x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7,x_8,x_9,x_{10}>= PolynomialRing(QQ,order='lex')`

`sagemath: f=(x_1-x_2)*(x_1-x_3)*(x_1-x_6)*(x_2-x_3)*(x_2-x_7)*(x_3-x_5)*(x_3-x_9)*(x_5-x_8)*(x_5-x_{10})*(x_8-x_4)`

`sagemath: I=Ideal(x_1^4-1, x_2^4-1, x_3^4-1, x_4^4-1,x_5^4-1,x_6^4-1, x_7^4-1, x_8^4-1,x_9^4-1,x_{10}^4-1)`

`sagemath: h=f.reduce(I)`

`sagemath: h`

Whereas when $f$ is reduced modulo $\langle x_i^5-1\rangle\ \ i\in\{1,2,\ldots,10\}$ yields remainder equal to $f$. Any explanation for this phenomenon? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Can you post an actual example to illustrate the issue?

Comment: @quasi take the polynomial $f=(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)(x_1-x_6)(x_2-x_3)(x_2-x_7)(x_3-x_5)(x_3-x_9)(x_5-x_8)(x_5-x_{10})(x_8-x_4)$ where $x_3,x_4,x_5,x_1,x_2, x_6, x_7,x_8, x_9, x_{10}$ are variables, which is homegeneous. Now, reduction of this modulo the ideal $\langle x_1^4-1, x_2^4-1, x_3^4-1, x_4^4-1,x_5^4-1,x_6^4-1, x_7^4-1, x_8^4-1,x_9^4-1,x_{10}^4-1\rangle$ yields a non-zero remainder not equal to $f$. Whereas when $f$ is reduced modulo $\langle x_i^5-1\rangle\ \ i\in\{1,2,\ldots,10\}$ yields remainder equal to $f$

Comment: To reproduce the issue you raised, can you post the associated sage code?

Comment: @quasi The sage code is added now.

Comment: Using your code, I get $h-f=0$. In other words, $f$ is already reduced.

Comment: @quasi is it? But I repeatedly performed the calculation and the output shows some other remainder. May be I have to clear the cache. Are you using the notebook interface, or are you doing it in terminal?

Comment: I'm using the CLI.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @quasi ok, so leaving the technical details aside, so theoretically, what I said before, that if the leading term of the ideal with respect to some ordering has its highest power of one variable higher than that of the polynomial, then the polynomial is already reduced with respect to the ideal right?(my ideal is as mentioned)

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @quasi my next question would be what would be the remainder if the highest power of the leading term of the ideal, that is, $k$ were to divide the highest power of the leading term of the homogeneous polynomial. When would we get zero, for example?

Comment: $f$ reduces to zero mod $I$ if and only if $f\in I$.

Comment: @quasi would the remainder be homogeneous if it is nonzero? What could the minimal total degree of a nonhomogeneous remainder?

Comment: The question in your latest comment is somewhat vague. I suggest that you experiment with much, much smaller examples, and then, based on the results, if a question arises, ask it as a new question, with example and code included as part of the post.